# Loading functions once page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I cant figure out where I have gone wrong. I am trying to have it so that a random index is selected then from that index the corresponding item in the array is chosen and displayed. However, at the moment nothing is being displayed. I think this is because the functions are not loading after the page has loaded and I'm not sure how to do this correctly. If you see any other errors in my current code please feel free to leave some feedback. Thanks :)

`JS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function getRandomVideo() {
            //Arrays for videos, titles, images, and searches
            var videos = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/kiTO7c_qeZs', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Hfv00eqoI', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cdZYQB5ONE', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/i1gE3nyQnKg', ];
            var titles = ['Beethoven - Music, Love and Wine', 'Mozart String Serenade No.13', 'Beethoven Sonata No. 31 in A Flat Major', "Debussy - Children's Corner", ];
            var images = ["url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')", "url('Assets/mozart.jpg')", "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')", "url('Assets/debussy.jpg')", ]
            var searches = ['beethoven+biography&s=0', 'wolfgang+mozart&s=0', 'beethoven+biography&s=0', 'Claude+Debussy&s=1', ];
            //Gets a random index then uses said index to select an option in the array
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
            var video = videos[rand];
            var title = titles[rand];
            var image = images[rand];
            var search = searches[rand];
            //replaces parts of html with selected option from array
            document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = title;
            document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = image;
            document.getElementById("randomVideo").src = video;
            return search
        }
        var apiKey = "jja10ssv4950uh65";
        //I want to do this function and the one abovevwhen the document is loaded
        $(document).onload(function() {
            var searchTerm = getRandomVideo();
            var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=" + apiKey + "&encoding=json&zone=newspaper&sortby=relevance&q=" + searchTerm + "&s=0&n=5&include=articletext,pdf&encoding=json&callback=?";
            console.log(url);
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                $('#output').empty();
                $.each(data.response.zone[0].records.article, function(index, value) {
                    $("#output").append("<p>" + value.articleText + "</p>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.onload` is not a jQuery method . At [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) at beginning of `js` `document` should be loaded at call to `$.getJSON()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // do stuff
 var apiKey = "jja10ssv4950uh65";
 var searchTerm = getRandomVideo();
 var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=" + apiKey + "&encoding=json&zone=newspaper&sortby=relevance&q=" + searchTerm + "&s=0&n=5&include=articletext,pdf&encoding=json&callback=?";
 console.log(url);
 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   $('#output').empty();
   $.each(data.response.zone[0].records.article, function(index, value) {
     $("#output").append("<p>" + value.articleText + "</p>");
   });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onload part from from your jquery code and it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function getRandomVideo() {
 //Arrays for videos, titles, images, and searches
 var videos = ['https://www.youtube.com/embed/kiTO7c_qeZs', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Hfv00eqoI', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cdZYQB5ONE', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/i1gE3nyQnKg', ];
 var titles = ['Beethoven - Music, Love and Wine', 'Mozart String Serenade No.13', 'Beethoven Sonata No. 31 in A Flat Major', "Debussy - Children's Corner", ];
 var images = ["url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')", "url('Assets/mozart.jpg')", "url('Assets/beethoven.jpg')", "url('Assets/debussy.jpg')", ]
 var searches = ['beethoven+biography&s=0', 'wolfgang+mozart&s=0', 'beethoven+biography&s=0', 'Claude+Debussy&s=1', ];
 //Gets a random index then uses said index to select an option in the array
 var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
 var video = videos[rand];
 var title = titles[rand];
 alert(title);
 var image = images[rand];
 var search = searches[rand];
 //replaces parts of html with selected option from array
 document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = title;
 document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage = image;
 document.getElementById("randomVideo").src = video;
 return search
}
var apiKey = "jja10ssv4950uh65";
//I want to do this function and the one abovevwhen the document is loaded
var searchTerm = getRandomVideo();
var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=" + apiKey + "&encoding=json&zone=newspaper&sortby=relevance&q=" + searchTerm + "&s=0&n=5&include=articletext,pdf&encoding=json&callback=?";
console.log(url);
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
 $('#output').empty();
 $.each(data.response.zone[0].records.article, function(index, value) {
  $("#output").append("<p>" + value.articleText + "</p>");
 });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="songTitle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function try like this...E.g:

```
<button onclick="$(function(){getRandomVideo()});">Test</button>
```

And let

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRandomVideo() {
          // Your codes..
     }
</script>
```